# How to run a PowerShell script in VB Script?

Tags: powershell-3.0, group-policy

I want to run the following PowerShell Script inside VB script without building a standalone PowerShell script and call it using the VB script:

```
    import-module grouppolicy 

function IsNotLinked($xmldata){ 
    If ($xmldata.GPO.LinksTo -eq $null) { 
        Return $true 
    } 

    Return $false 
} 

$unlinkedGPOs = @() 

Get-GPO -All | ForEach { $gpo = $_ ; $_ | Get-GPOReport -ReportType xml | ForEach { If(IsNotLinked([xml]$_)){$unlinkedGPOs += $gpo} }} 

If ($unlinkedGPOs.Count -eq 0) { 
    "No Unlinked GPO's Found" 
} 
Else{ 
    $unlinkedGPOs | Select DisplayName,ID | ft 
}
```

What is recommended to be done?
Thanks in advance